# Java ServletDispatcher crossContext not working as expected for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Demo of Problem : https://github.com/paul-hammant/servletDispatcherTest

I've tried Tomcat 6 and 7.

Synopsis: If you change conf/context.xml to have an attribute 'crossContext="true"' then one war file app can leverage another within the same Tomcat instance.  It works, but not as expected.

I have two WAR-file web apps in the demo above 'a' and 'b'.  Only one servlet for each, that spits out text rather than HTML. In fact it simply tries to print out the current thread's object-identity.

Here is what Tomcat puts out on a page when trying to access /a/

```
message The requested resource (/b/anything) is not available

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/b/anything) is not available
org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:776)
org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:411)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
servletDispatcherTest.A.doFilter(A.java:31)
```

Quick URLs to the source for A.java and B.java:
https://github.com/paul-hammant/servletDispatcherTest/blob/master/a/src/main/java/servletDispatcherTest/A.java and  https://github.com/paul-hammant/servletDispatcherTest/blob/master/b/src/main/java/servletDispatcherTest/B.java

I're really expecting output like:

```
A thread = 610988429
B thread = 610988429
```

A direct access to /b/anything works as expected, as would an access to /a if it were not for the attempt to dispatch:

```
ServletContext context = httpsr.getSession().getServletContext().getContext("/b");
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/anything");
requestDispatcher.include(request, response);
```

Comment: I got this working, if anyone is interested. The github project above has a working two-webapp demo of one webapp leveraging another w/o opening a socket, or spawning a new thread.